# Sum index values of an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, sum

I want to sum values according to arguments received in command-line. Example : when the user types `node program.js 5 7 3`, I want the following output :

```
0: /usr/bin/node 
1: /home/<pathtotheprogram>/program.js 
2: 5
3: 7
4: 3
5: 15
```

I am using this loop to pass through the number arguments received in command-line :

```
process.argv.forEach( (val, index)=> {
    //program logic
})
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `let sum = process.argv.slice(2).reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b), 0)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a detailed answer.

```
const args = process.argv;
let sum = 0;

if (args.length > 2) {
    for (let i = 2, l = args.length; i < l; i++) {
        sum += parseInt(args[i], 10);
    }
}

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't understood this line code : sum += parseInt(args[i], 10); Can you explain it?

Comment: The ```parseInt(args[i], 10)``` is make the argument integer. The arguments from process are converted to string. So you need to parse it to integer.